# Keras feature extractor clarification - which layers does an input goes through

Tags: tensorflow, keras, feature-extraction

When extracting a model layer output as in the Tensorflow sequential model document example below, does the input `x` in the code go through the `my_first_layer` as well before going into `my_intermediate_layer` layer? Or does it directly go into the `my_intermediate_layer` layer without going through the `my_first_layer` layer?

If it directly goes into the `my_intermediate_layer`, the input to the `my_intermediate_layer` does not have the transformation done by `my_first_layer` Conv2D. However, it seems not right to me because the input should go through all the preceding layers.

Please help understand what layers does x go through?

[Feature extraction with a Sequential model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model#feature_extraction_with_a_sequential_model)

```
initial_model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(250, 250, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 5, strides=2, activation="relu", name="my_first_layer"),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", name="my_intermediate_layer"),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
    ]
)

# The model goes through the training.
...

# Feature extractor
feature_extractor = keras.Model(
    inputs=initial_model.inputs,
    outputs=initial_model.get_layer(name="my_intermediate_layer").output,
)
# Call feature extractor on test input.
x = tf.ones((1, 250, 250, 3))
features = feature_extractor(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras offers higher level of API, which runs on top of the TensorFlow machine learning platform. Keras offers two types of class to define the neural network model, namely 'Sequential Class' and 'Model Class.'

**Sequential Class:** 
It groups a linear stack of layers to form a model, such that each layer has one input and one output tensor. One can add required layers to the defined model (schema-1) as shown below to execute sequentially as name suggests [Keras Sequential Class](https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/),

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(16,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4))
```

The schema for defining a sequential model [Keras-Sequential Class Definition](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/) has shown below (schema-2),

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
    ]
)
# Call model on a test input
x = tf.ones((3, 3))
y = model(x)
```

**Model Class** 
It allows the user to build a custom model along with many layers as shown below,

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

It allows one to create a new functional API model with additional layers [Keras - Model Class](https://keras.io/api/models/model/) as follows,

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
processed = keras.layers.RandomCrop(width=32, height=32)(inputs)
conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=3)(processed)
pooling = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(conv)
feature = keras.layers.Dense(10)(pooling)
```

Note: The input tensors supports only dicts, lists or tuples but not lists of list, or dicts of dict.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, however is this related with a feature extractor from a trained model?

Comment: I think that when the schema-2 is being used, it allows only to extract the features output from specific layers. But the inputs goes to the first_layer, and then the intermediate layer. One can extract features from all layers using iterations, else output from specific layers as mentioned in the link, (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model#feature_extraction_with_a_sequential_model)